# The date functions in snowflake doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I can't understand why

`SELECT YEAROFWEEK('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00'::timestamp)` returns "2016"

`SELECT WEEK('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00'::timestamp)` returns "52"

Can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the doc for the week of the year policy that decides how this works -  https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#week-of-year-policy

An example might help. *week_of_year_policy* is set to 0 by default on newly created accounts.

```
select YEAROFWEEK('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00'::timestamp) as yow
     , WEEK('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00'::timestamp) as w;

+------+----+
|  YOW |  W |
+------+----+
| 2016 | 52 |
+------+----+

alter session set week_of_year_policy = 1;

select YEAROFWEEK('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00'::timestamp) as yow
     , WEEK('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00'::timestamp) as w;

+------+---+
|  YOW | W |
+------+---+
| 2017 | 1 |
+------+---+
```

Comment: Your answer seems to show OP how to get what he needs, but perhaps might me more helpful if you could explain why.  E.g. what is week_of_year_policy? Or link to docs.

Comment: OP had already linked to the docs in their update so I didn't duplicate, but appreciate this would have been a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

With slightly more digging got my answer from https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#week-of-year-policy

Comment: and would you like to explain "for yourself/others" what parameters where in play, otherwise this "question" and "answers" has little value.